# Item duplication while incrementing the items inside the cart

Tags: reactjs, redux, cart

I am developing a shopping cart where users add the items to the cart and checkout with the payment.

The problem when I try to add items from home page or from the category page, for example, I clicked the Bluetooth headset for items four times in the cart it should show the product count as 4 but it shows as the four different items repeatedly as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Iuf.jpg) and when I add one product into the cart and try to increase the quantity slowly it shows the quantity of the product correctly but when I try to increase the quantity with fast click it creates the duplicate of the product with the same quantity and increases the bill amount as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSFt0.jpg) it created 4 duplicate items when I try to increase items in the cart

I tried the below code

```
    /* Increase product qty */
  IncreaseItem(value, prodid, cartid) {
    const value_stock = value + 1
    this.onchange(value_stock, prodid, cartid)
  }

  /* Increment button call to check with stock */
  IncrementItem(e, prodid, cartid) {
    const value = this.quantity_value
    this.mapprodstock(value, prodid, cartid)
  }
```

Down below is the component that is created and added

```
<Wrapper>
    <Btn onClick={e => this.DecreaseItem(e.target.value, this.props.productidval, this.props.cartidval)}> - </Btn>
    <InputField
      value={this.quantity_value}
      onChange={e => this.onchange(e.target.value, this.props.productidval, this.props.cartidval)}
    />
    <Btn onClick={e => this.IncrementItem(e.target.value, this.props.productidval, this.props.cartidval)}> + </Btn>
    <Message>{this.state.message}</Message>
  </Wrapper>
```

This is the `mapprodstock` function

```
    /* Get the product item and store in state to get article number */
  mapprodstock = async (value, prodid, cartid) => {
    const productid = prodid
    const apiUrl = `${endpointCustomProduct()}${productid}`
    const params = {
      access_token: handleGetToken(),
      fields: '*.*',
    }
    const response = await CustomproductService({ url: apiUrl, params })
    this.setState({
      product_data: response,
    })
    const articlenumber = _.map(this.state.product_data, (item) => {
      return item.article_number
    })
    this.checkstock(value, prodid, cartid, articlenumber)
  }
```

and the `onchange` function

```
    /* change in input value to store qty */
  async onchange(value_stock, prodid, cartid) {
    this.quantity_value = value_stock
    this.cartService(cartid, prodid, value_stock)
  }
```

And even I tried to disable the increment button and decrement buttons while updating the product but it still duplicating the row

Can I know where is the mistake

Comment: You need to show the code for `mapprodstock` and `onchange` methods.

Comment: @Clarity can you check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async, so if you need to get the newest state after it's been updated, use the callback for it:

```
  const response = await CustomproductService({ url: apiUrl, params});

  this.setState({
    product_data: response,
  }, () => { // Use callback here
    const articlenumber = _.map(this.state.product_data, (item) => {
      return item.article_number
    })
    this.checkstock(value, prodid, cartid, articlenumber)
  }))
```

Comment: no, the callback function not working still facing the same issue. is there any other method for not duplicating the cart